# Where does Flutter store the assets in the assets folder on the phone?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, local-storage

I am interested in finding out the path where Flutter stores local files, the ones defined in the pubspec.yaml file. Is it a private location that only the app can access, or can I manually find it on the phone?

I want to make some audio files available only for premium users and I would like to store them locally, on the user's phone. I don't know if they can access those audio files without any trouble even if they are not premium users, just by looking them up. Could they find them by browsing the phone's folders?

Is there a storage limit to the Flutter assets folder?

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be accessed without extracting the APK. As the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#:%7E:text=Flutter%20uses%20the%20pubspec.,assets%20required%20by%20an%20app.) says that *"An asset is a file that is bundled and deployed with your app and is accessible at runtime"*

PS: So can exactly do premium and non premium thing it is only available in run time

Comment: The documentation doesn't say it's a private directory. It only says apps can access it at runtime. Doesn't mention the case when the user has the app downloaded from Google Play on the phone.

Comment: You can experimentally test and see that by using APK extractor

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try it out @sid